# Sails create probleme

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I just want to create a new input in my db by sailsjs, but no error and no entree come out.

Here's my model

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    id: { type: 'integer'},
    entreprise_id: { type: 'integer'},
    employees_id: { type: 'string'},
    name : { type: 'string'},
    description_short: { type: 'string'},
    description_long: { type: 'string'},
    price: { type: 'string'},
    duration: { type: 'string'},
    at_home: {type: 'integer'},
    break_time: {type: 'integer'},
    many_customer: {type: 'integer'},
    last_minute_max: {type: 'integer'},
    precision_label: {type: 'string'},
    createdAt : { type: 'date' }, 
    updatedAt : { type: 'date' }

  }

}
```

and the script to create the entree

```
Service.create({

  entreprise_id: entrepriseId,
  employees_id:infos['employees_id'],
  name :infos['name'],
  description_short:infos['description_short'],
  description_long:infos['description_long'],
  price:infos['price'],
  duration:infos['duration'],
  at_home:infos['at_home'],
  break_time:infos['break_time'],
  many_customer:infos['many_customer'],
  last_minute_max:infos['last_minute_max'],
  precision_label:infos['precision_label']  

}).exec( function(err, newService){

  if(err){ com.push({error:err})}
  else{
    com.push(newService)
  }

});
```

I have already verify all informations in the **info** Array are empty or contains value but no error there.
The strenge thing is that I have no error in my **com** array and no newservice as wall.

Comment: 1. What is name of your model file? 2. How are you running the script? 3. Where is `com` array initialized and checked? 4. Did you try putting logs?

Comment: 1. Service.js ; 2. I run the script with grunt on console, sailsjs ; 3. The array com is initialized on the top of the script and I use it as log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly get the error by adding "if(err){  return res.serverError(err); }" in my callback function.

I had to prevent the empty value where number was required etc

```
for(n in infos){

  if(n=='entreprise_id'){ infos[n] = entrepriseId; }
  if(n=="price"||n=="duration"||n=="at_home"||n=="break_time"||n=="many_customer"||n=="last_minute_max"){
    if(!infos[n]){
      infos[n]=0;
    }
  }

}

Service.create({
  entreprise_id: infos['entreprise_id'],
  employees_id:infos['employees_id'],
  name :infos['name'],
  description_short:infos['description_short'],
  description_long:infos['description_long'],
  price:infos['price'],
  duration:infos['duration'],
  at_home:infos['at_home'],
  break_time:infos['break_time'],
  many_customer:parseInt(infos['many_customer']),
  last_minute_max:parseInt(infos['last_minute_max']),
  precision_label:infos['precision_label']         
}).exec( function(err, newService){

  if(err){  return res.serverError(err); }
  com.push({news:newService})

});
```